# I can't seem to center my website, I have a width set for the container and have margin set to margin:0 auto;

Tags: html, css

The project in question is http://www.JamesRobertCook.com which I've uploaded the site to so you guys might be able to help me figure out where I goofed. Like the title says, I've set a width on my container and set the body to margin:0 auto; and I am at a loss here.

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed! I was silly and put the margin: 0 auto on body instead of my container. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you have a doctype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to add `margin: 0 auto;`.  It is working.

```
#container {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It's always something silly. I thought that margin:0 auto; had to be applied to the body. My mistake, thanks for the quick fix! Will mark as answer because you were the first though @Pete Scott got it as well.

Comment: @MrS1ck I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your div#container is lacking a margin:0 auto;.

You've got margin:0 auto set on the body element. You want it on the #container element.